# Spotify Web API python requests unable to access public playlist information

Tags: python, api, python-requests, spotify

```
import requests
import json

CLIENT_ID = 'xxxx'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxx'

AUTH_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'

auth_response = requests.post(AUTH_URL, {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
})

# convert the response to JSON
auth_response_data = auth_response.json()

# save the access token
access_token = auth_response_data['access_token']

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {token}'.format(token=access_token),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'

}


# base URL of all Spotify API endpoints
BASE_URL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/'

# Playlist ID from the URI
playlist_id = '5GEf0fJs9xBPr5R4jEQjtw'

# actual GET request with proper header
playlist_response = requests.get(BASE_URL + 'playlist/'+playlist_id, headers=headers)

#Track ID from the URI
track_id = '6y0igZArWVi6Iz0rj35c1Y'
track_response = requests.get(BASE_URL + 'audio-features/' + track_id, headers=headers)
print(playlist_response.text)
print(track_response.text)
```

So with this code, the track_response returns:

```
{
"danceability" : 0.540,
"energy" : 0.590,
"key" : 0,
"loudness" : -4.359,
"mode" : 1,
"speechiness" : 0.0528,
"acousticness" : 0.446,
"instrumentalness" : 0,
"liveness" : 0.140,
"valence" : 0.267,
"tempo" : 119.878,
"type" : "audio_features",
"id" : "6y0igZArWVi6Iz0rj35c1Y",
"uri" : "spotify:track:6y0igZArWVi6Iz0rj35c1Y",
"track_href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/6y0igZArWVi6Iz0rj35c1Y",
"analysis_url" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/6y0igZArWVi6Iz0rj35c1Y",
"duration_ms" : 234910,
"time_signature" : 4
}
```

But when I try and repeat this to obtain information about the playlist, I receive a 404 error saying that the service is not found. I have found this is the same case for albums when I use BASE_URL + 'album/' + id. How can I get this to return some playlist information?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your intention to get track features from all tracks in a playlist? If so, you will have to make a GET request to the the /audio-features endpoint, using a list of comma-separated track IDs inside the playlist, as explained in the [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-several-audio-features).

Comment: Yep, that's right but I can't seem to retrieve the track IDs from the playlist in order to loop through and get the audio features. It keeps saying that the service cannot be found when I use the GET request

Comment: this happens for every playlist I have tried